# format descriptor for unsigned short * in IOS 6

Tags: objective-c

In my code I have some strings in unichar format with definition like below

```
unichar sourceString[100];
```

After I assign value to sourceString, I need to put it into an NSString with proper format descriptor.

Previously in IOS 5, I used %S, and it worked just fine. The code is as follows

```
NSString * targetString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%S",sourceString];
```

But after I upgraded SDK to IOS 6.0, warnings comes up with the same code:

```
**Format specifies type 'const unsigned short *' but the argument has type 'unichar *' (aka 'unsigned short *')**
```

My app still works but there are hundreds of warnings when the code is compiled, which is really annoying.

I am wondering what is the correct format descriptor I shall use in this case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Using `const unichar sourceString[100];` will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you try using %hu the warning still appears?

Seeing format types at: http://reference.jumpingmonkey.org/programming_languages/objective-c/types.html

Comment: Thank you. I tried %hu, but there is still warning. This time it is  "Format specifies type 'unsigned short' but the argument has type 'unichar *' (aka 'unsigned short *')"